# How to use different colors of texts in same Excel cell using ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, closedxml

How to use different colors of texts in the same Excel cell using ClosedXML?

`worksheet.Cell(1,1).Value.Character[StartIndex, NoOfChar].Font.Color....??`

ClosedXML doesn't have something like above, please help me to use two different font colors in the same cell.

Comment: try worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Style.Font.FontColor

Comment: Thanks but I tried the same,this will apply the color to whole cell text.I need portion of the text to be colored.@Innat3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `RichText` to style different parts of the cell, for example:

```
worksheet.Cell(1,1).RichText.Substring(StartIndex, NoOfChar).SetFontColor(XLColor.Red);
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Rich-Text) for more details.

Comment: *worksheet.Cell(1,1).RichText.Substring(StartIndex, NoOfChar).SetFontColor(XLColor.Red);

Comment: @Raidri, you seem to know the library well. We could use your help in developing it further. http://github.com/Closedxml/Closedxml

Comment: strangely, i get this error. Is RichText deprecated in ClosedXML?
CS1061: "XLCell" does not contain a definition for 'RichText' and no accessible extension method 'Rich Text accepting a first argument of type 'IXLCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)